# Weird Induction...?

Tags: probability, induction

I was watching [this video](https://youtu.be/T99VmLuQDgg) earlier and I couldnt figure out why the following step was possible. This is the original problem:

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{2n + 1}{n + 1}$

At one point, this somehow becomes:

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{n + k + 1}{k}$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$

Since it was a video, I couldnt really ask the person... I'm very stuck trying to figure this out...

---

**Edit:** the link has been added above. You can also find it [here](https://youtu.be/T99VmLuQDgg). The link should start the video at 4:44, where the relevant formula appears.

Comment: If that were true then the single number on the left would be equal to multiple different numbers on the right.

Comment: It would be helpful to add the source/video if you can.

Comment: your second formula is apparerently wong: it says that $\binom{n + k + 1}{k}$ is constant, independent of $k$. So check your formula, you made an error. It is $$\sum_{i = 0}^{k} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{n + k + 1}{k}$$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are either misinterpreting the video, the video is wrong, or something else is going on because, if

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{2n + 1}{n + 1}$

and

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{n + k + 1}{k}$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$,

that would imply

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{2n + 1}{n + 1} = \binom{n + k + 1}{k}$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$,

and, more specifically,

$\binom{2n + 1}{n + 1} = \binom{n + k + 1}{k}$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$.

However, I can show you a counterexample of the fourth statement when $n = 4$ and $k = 2$:

$\binom{2 * 4 + 1}{4 + 1} = \binom{4 + 2 + 1}{2}$ and $0 \leq 2 \leq 4$

$\binom{9}{5} = \binom{7}{2}$

$126 = 21$

The last statement is of course a contradiction, so the premise is false.

---

**Edit:** I suspect it may be the case that

$\sum_{i = 0}^{k} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{n + k + 1}{k}$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$,

but that's just a hunch. I may investigate further.

---

**Edit:**

First of all, the second equation you wrote in your question is not used in the video. It should actually be this:

$\sum_{i = 0}^{k} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{n + k + 1}{k}$ (Eq. 1)

Note the $k$ in the summation.

Second of all, when we look at the video, at 3:37 she writes

$\sum_{i = 0}^{k} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{n + k + i}{k}$,

but it should be Eq. 1 (from above). In the video she writes $n + k + i$ in the binomial coefficient when it should be $n + k + 1$.

She then proves that Eq. 1 is true using induction. This is useful for reasons that you may already understand, but if not, here's an explanation:

If Eq. 1 is proven true, then we can let $k=n$, then replace all the $k$'s with $n$'s. If we do that, then we get this:

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{n + n + 1}{n}$.

Now, as she says at 9:19,

$\binom{A + B}{A} = \binom{A + B}{B}$.

In our case, $A=n$ and $B=n+1$, so we can write

$\binom{n + n + 1}{n} = \binom{n + n + 1}{n + 1}$,

and thus

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{n + n + 1}{n} = \binom{n + n + 1}{n + 1}$,

which can also be expressed as

$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{2n + 1}{n}$.

So as long as Eq. 1 is proven true, we can prove the question statement. The video proves Eq. 1 is true using induction.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T99VmLuQDgg&list=PLYZlcsMwMhDyW-wE2JQjioXgitqdEZ505&index=4 maybe this would help? It starts at 4:44

Comment: After watching the video, I have revised my answer. I believe the second equation in your question is not what is used in the video.